# Get LastWriteTime of Multiple Files in Directory

Tags: .net

I'm a novice, working on an SSIS package and thanks to some assistance by talented folks here, such as yourselves, I've been able to get it to work, but am running into an issue. I need to pull data from 2 flat files and then insert it into a SQL table, to which I've added a derived column to input the LastWriteTime of the files from the directory. What's happening is that instead of pulling in the LastWriteTime of the files, it's inserting it of the directory. I know this because I've been copying/pasting different files into the directory and tried working with older files, but the date that is being inserted into the table is today's date, and not the older date of the files, themselves. I have the following that I'm using in a script task:

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim FilePath As String = "D:\InputFiles\"
        Dim finf As New System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath)
        Dts.Variables("User::FileDate").Value = finf.LastWriteTime

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
EndSub
```

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `FileInfo` for the directory.

Instead, you need to get multiple `FileInfo`s for the files in the directory, by calling `new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles()`.

Comment: Hi SLaks, Thanks for the advice. So I tried the following per your suggestion: Public Sub Main() Dim filePath As String = "D:\InputFiles\" Dim fileDirec As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(filePath) fileDirec.GetFiles() Dts.Variables("User::FileDate").Value = fileDirec.LastWriteTime Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
, but it's still inserting today's date rather than the date of the LastWriteTime of the files, into the table. Any thoughts anyone??

Comment: Do you understand what you just wrote? You're still getting the `LastWriteTime` of the directory.  You need a loop or a LINQ query.

Comment: Okay, so I tried a for-each loop: 

Dim filePath As String = "D:\InputFiles" Dim fileDirec As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(filePath)
For Each file In fileDirec.GetFiles()

            Dts.Variables("User::FileDate").Value = fileDirec.LastWriteTime
        Next

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
...but still no luck.....what am I doing wrong...I'm sorry but I'm just a beginner, trying to learn as I go...I appreciate all the assistance.

Comment: `fileDirec` is not the same as `file`.  Also, _which_ file's date do you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...I have declared fileDirec to look at the filePath, "D:\InputFiles", where the files are stored. There are 2 files, both of which will have the same date. Please let me know if can further clarify.

Comment: That worked.........I changed it to file.LastWriteTime and it's not correctly inserting the files' LastWriteTime into the column. Thanks, Slaks!